# Theoretical IOPS value for a Raid Controller/Raid Array

Tags: raid, hp

Gents,
  We have a database server (Oracle), its raid array is read intensive...  Raid Controller type:

```
04:00.0 RAID bus controller: Hewlett-Packard Company Smart Array G6 controllers (rev 01)
07:00.0 RAID bus controller: Hewlett-Packard Company Smart Array G6 controllers (rev 01)
```

Here are the values we are seeing via iostat:

```
cciss/c1d0     4933.00    788848.00      7088.00     788848       7088
```

File system is ext3...  Can/should we expect greater performance from this setup?

Anything specific you would recommend I check/do?

Thanks!!!

Comment: We're missing some of the details. Which server model is this? I'm assuming the controller is a Smart Array P410i, however, the number type and RAID arrangement of the disks would also be helpful.

Comment: @ewwhite cciss0: HP Smart Array P410i Controller.   Logical drives: 2   Raid 1(1+0)

Comment: What are the drives? 10k? 15k?

Comment: mmmm, not sure...  lets assume 10K

Answer (score 3):

You don't say what controller you have but most G6 servers come with a P410i, which has a PCIe 2.O x8 connector. So that could, at least theoretically, deliver 4GBps Either way, so if we take typical 4k reads and writes, 100% from cache and without overhead you'd be able to read and write that same block ~1m times per second both ways.

Of course this is all entirely theoretical because you won't want to actually do that but then you've only given us maybe 2% of the information we'd actually need to help you but it does answer your question as written.

Comment: Now you've told us some (small) information then even if you've got a pair of 146GB 15krpm disks in that box then ignoring controller and disk caching the most you've get our a R1 (it's not a R10 if you only have 2 disks) will be ~2x180 IOPS, so 360 for random read/write. So if you're seeing nearly 5k IOPS you must be getting a hell of a lot of successful cache hits

Comment: Typo sorry, 360 for read, 180 for write.

Comment: Thanks!!!  So how do you make a correlation between 2x180 and 8000 IOPS :)  So what I can read from this is... we are maxing the IOPS on this controller... hardware bottleneck is the answer

Comment: where can i get the first number you are saying?  The 2x180 IOPS?  Is it the cat /proc/driver/cciss/cciss1 ?  or somewhere else, or just a known hardware spec

Comment: That's the max guarunteed non-cached random read/write capability of those disks, I buy them too.